# How can I remove audit logs of auid = -1

Tags: log

I'm trying to configure auditd for audit log.

What I want to do is remove logs of auid=-1(auid=4294967295).

I tried few things but the result was same.
(Set rules in audit.rules file, etc..)

Anything that I can try will be helpful.

[info]
4.13.0.-39-generic
16.04.1-ubuntu

using Linux Mint Sylvia

[audit report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuIle.png)